# Value of type 'NavigationController' has no member

Tags: swift, firebase, github, messenger, navigationcontroller

I have downloaded this messenger code from a github repository and i have set everything up (from what I'm aware of) such as the firebase and installed the cocoa pops.  Everything seems to be running fine except 14 errors which all say the same thing reading -

> "Value of type 'NavigationController' has no member 'isModalInPresentation'"

or

> "Value of type 'LoginEmailView' has no member 'isModalInPresentation'"

or

> "Value of type 'RegisterEmailView' has no member 'isModalInPresentation'"

I have attached some of the code :)

```
@IBAction func actionLoginPhone(_ sender: Any) {

    let loginPhoneView = LoginPhoneView()
    loginPhoneView.delegate = self
    let navController = NavigationController(rootViewController: loginPhoneView)
    navController.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        navController.isModalInPresentation = true
        navController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    }
    present(navController, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: The code must be compiled with Xcode 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be an issue of your SDK version.

The given instance property isModalInPresentation was introduced in SDK iOS 13+ only, so you must have that or a later version of SDK.

Otherwise, what version SDK does your Xcode have?

Comment: how do i check the SDK version ?

Comment: oh wait i think mine is 12.1